# .htaccess RewriteRule to remove ? following hostname

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an htaccess file with some rules, and I now want to add another rule which strips a part of the URL such that

> www.mydomain.com/?generations/anything

becomes

> www.mydomain.com/anything

(and anything means any other characters).  I can make it work without the ?, but I can't seem to match/remove the ?.   I tried:

## 1 failed:

```
RewriteRule ^\?generations/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

## 2 failed:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^generations/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^generations/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

## 3 failed:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^generations/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)?generations/(.*)$ $2%1 [L]
```

## 4 failed:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)?generations/(.*)$ $1$2 [QSA,L]
```

Can someone create a working rule - and explain why my third attempt above is not working?  I can potentially see problems with the first two, but the third and fourth should work...

Answer (score 1):

You're getting there with 3, but the query string is not included in a RewriteRule match. So you just want to match the empty string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^generations/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ %1? [L]
```

But you also have it the wrong way round I think, if you want /anything to be the URL that is visited in the browser. You actually want just this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?generations/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Could you explain your first code block?  What does ^$ do?  And in your second block, are the pattern and replacement strings reversed?

Comment: First code block, ^$ just says match the empty string, as in just mydomain.com/ since the query string is matched separately. In the second, the point is, if you want people visiting mydomain.com/anything to actually get mydomain.com/?generations/anything then you need to do it the other way round. So yes, reversed the way you were doing it.

Comment: But I wanted to remove the "?generations/" from the URL.  Does that mean your answer is reversed?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm saying in the second part of my answer. That is how you remove the '?generations/" from the URL. Not the way you were trying. Try it and see!